# How do load an image into a 2D array element?

Tags: arrays, delphi, multidimensional-array, pascal, timage

I'm currently doing my A-Level Computing project for which I am making my own version of the classic game Space Invaders.

To create the wave of space invaders I want to use a 2D array of images, where the images are loaded from a disk and then displayed on the form but I am unsure of how load the images into the array and then display the array on a form.

The current arrays are:

```
ImagePaths:array [1..3] of string =('SpaceInvader1.jpg', 'SpaceInvader2.jpg', 'SpaceInvader3.jpg'); 

Wave:array[1..11, 1..5] of TImage; x,y:integer;
```

What I would like to know is: how would I load an image into an array element? eg how would I load 'SpaceInvader1.jpg' to array element [1,1]?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 11 times 5 does not equal 3. What am I missing?

Comment: This is what I am trying to recreate by using a 2D array of images http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_2TCYQxSUqGQ/TIetTqkVf5I/AAAAAAAAKYw/buxwoNO2UCU/s1600/space%2520invaders.jpg Specifically the wave of space invaders

Comment: Why do you need a 2D array of images? What are the two dimensions?

Comment: my teacher told me to use a 2D array of images to create the wave of space invaders, eg [1..11,1..5] and each element in the array is an image so when you draw it onto the form it creates the wave of space invaders

Comment: That's not how I would do it! I'd have an array of those dimensions which contained the state of the invader. Then the render code would draw the appropriate representation of that state.

Comment: so would this idea not work then?: create a 2D array of images with dimensions [1..11, 1..5] then for each element load an image into it and then draw the array on the form. That is the way that I want to do it really because my teacher can help me with it if necessary and that is the way he advised.

Comment: What happens when an invader is killed? Why do you want all those identical copies of the image? Or are you going to create a small library of images and have the array contain references to those images? Anyway, if you want to do it your way, you don't our advice, why don't you just do it your way? And what's more, you didn't actually ask a question. What is your specific question?

Comment: How can you not have identical copies of the same image in space invaders? I understand that this may not be the best method solve this problem and your way is probably better but I have only been programming for about a year and so I am not that good yet. I just wanna know if this way would work and how you would load the image into the array that is all.

Comment: This problem is similar but not quite the same as what I want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612740/loading-images-into-timage-via-array

Comment: "How can you not have identical copies of the same image in space invaders?" Well, I could explain how. But you want to do it your way. So, I won't bother.

Comment: I want to do it my way yes, as it is the way my teacher recommended for me to approach it. I understand that it may not be the best way, and your approach will be better but it is probably too advanced for me. I would like you to explain how I would create the 2D array (what variables I would need etc) and then how to load the images into it

Comment: Do you know how to use arrays? Do you know how to create images? If so, then you already know what you need to know.

Comment: The thing that I really don't understand is the loading of the images into the array elements

Comment: What don't you understand? Your question is very poor. All the details are in comments. Please improve the question. Did you declare the array yet? What does the declaration look like?

Comment: ImagePaths:array [1..3] of string =('SpaceInvader1.jpg', 'SpaceInvader2.jpg', 'SpaceInvader3.jpg');

Wave:array[1..11, 1..5] of TImage;

x,y:integer;

Comment: Now, how would I load for example 'SpaceInvader1.jpg' into element 1,1 in the array?

Comment: Create the image with TImage.Create. Load it with LoadFromFile. Don't use lossy jpeg. Use PNG or GIF. You really don't need multiple copies, but you are dead set on doing it your way....

Comment: Please please please edit the question to include this information. Don't leak it out in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much. I only want to do it this way because it is not too complicated (it doesn't need to be massively complex, it is only an A-Level project) and if I get stuck doing it, my teacher can advise and help me in lesson.

Comment: Your edit does little to address my concerns. All the good details have come out in comments. My answer relies on those comments. But they should be in the question. Please keep trying.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be coding graphical animations, you probably won't want to do it directly on the form.  Trying to move things around can be tricky, especially if you want to animate smoothly and not get a lot of flicker and graphical artifacts.

It would be better to use a rendering library.  The workflow goes like this:

- Create a rendering context on the form.  This is a control that provides a surface for graphical animations to run on.
- Load your three images into memory.
- Create an array of objects to represent the game data associated with your monsters.  (Position, movement direction and speed, etc.)  It can be flat or 2D, whichever works better for you.
- Set up a render loop that goes like this:

  - For each monster in the array, draw it at its position.
  - Draw the player's ship and all projectiles.
  - Check for collisions and handle appropriately.
  - Check for player input and handle appropriately.

You can find plenty of information on rendering libraries for Delphi in the forums at [Pascal Game Development](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com).

Answer (score 2):

You have the following declarations:

```
ImagePaths:array [1..3] of string =(
  'SpaceInvader1.jpg', 
  'SpaceInvader2.jpg', 
  'SpaceInvader3.jpg'
); 
Wave: array[1..11, 1..5] of TImage;
```

You want to know how to populate the array of images. It is quite wasteful to create 55 images when 3 will suffice. So instead of that, use indirection. Store references to the images. And `TImage` is a visual component, and so not appropriate for a sprite.

I would hold the images in an array like this:

```
Sprites: array [1..3] of TBitmap;
```

And populate it

```
JPEGImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
try
  for i := 1 to 3 do 
  begin
    JPEGImage.LoadFromFile(ImagePaths[i]);
    Sprites[i] := TBitmap.Create;
    Sprites[i].Assign(JPEGImage);
  end;
finally
  JPEGImage.Free;
end;
```

Then populate your `Wave` array like this, for example:

```
Wave: array[1..11, 1..5] of TBitmap; 
....
for i := 1 to 11 do
  for j := 1 to 5 do
    Wave[i,j] := Sprites[1];// or whichever sprite you want
```

Of course your sprites may be better with a real name rather than in an array.

---

Some other comments:

1. JPEG is a bad format for a game sprite. It is a lossy format. A plain Windows bitmap would be fine, as would a GIF or PNG.
2. I'd much rather see the images as embedded resources. Then your executable can stand alone.
3. I'd also far rather see your `Waves` array holding the state of each invader. And then you would create a function that would render that state onto a canvas.

Comment: Cheers for your advice and for sticking with me, I know that I didn't make what I wanted to do that clear. I'll try this out tomorrow when I get into college. Can I message you if I run into any other problems?

Comment: You can leave a comment if you want clarification. If that comment strays too far from this question then we'll suggest that you write another question. However, I'd like you to take the time, now, to fix up this question to include the missing details. The code that came in comments needs to be there.

Comment: What is the best way to draw the array onto the form once it is full with images?

Comment: It depends. On the rest of your game's design.

Comment: can you use Canvas.Draw (array)?

Comment: No you cannot draw an array. You have to draw each image separately.

Comment: That is how you destroy an object. Surely you've covered that in class.